# iText7 Bug: Endless loop in ImageRenderer

Tags: itext, itext7

i came across an endless-loop-issue due to floating point arithmetic in iText7 DotNet ImageRenderer.
I've added an image with 2464x3692 pixels to an PDF page area of 523x770 pixels, causing the Layout() function to loop endlessly because every iteration returned LayoutResult.NOTHING.

The main issue is that the image height is calculated inside the Layout-function using the following statement:

```
Line 90: height = (float)width / imageWidth * imageHeight;
```

Due to the floating point operation the height got a value of something like 770.0001.
This is greater than the area height, causing the loop to return LayoutResult.NOTHING, so the image gets autoscaled again.
Inside the AutoScale-function only the image width is checked, which IS inside the area boundaries and so nothing is scaled.

I've fixed this issue by changing the following code inside ImageRenderer.cs:

```
90 - height = (float)width / imageWidth * imageHeight;
90 + float? propHeight = RetrieveHeight();
91 + height = propHeight == null ? (float)width / imageWidth * imageHeight : propHeight.Value;

214 - SetProperty(Property.HEIGHT, UnitValue.CreatePointValue(area.GetBBox().GetHeight()));
215 + SetProperty(Property.HEIGHT, area.GetBBox().GetHeight());
```

ImageRenderer now uses the height that is set inside AutoScale without recalculating it if not necessary.

Hopefully this will be fixed in one of the next releases. :)

Regards
Yosh

Comment: Why you add it here? You should add it in the bugtracking System of itext

Comment: Jens is mostly right. The issue tracker is only for customers with a support contract, but since you already have modified code, you can submit a pull request directly on the GitHub repo (https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/pulls). Put the text of your StackOverflow question (the actual text, not a link to it) in the comment of the pull request. You can use MarkDown for formatting.

Comment: Yeah - mostly. Of course i wanted to report this issue to itexts bugtracking - but there is none (for non paying customers).
And cause i'm just evaluating the library for future use and have already tracked down the problem, i'm sorry, but i'm not willing to clone the repo, create test-cases, run the test-suite etc. just to report a bug.
Regards